# Android - Exporting a Project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, export, installation

What are the options for exporting a project (into a jar or something) if I want to be able to allow anyone to easily install the app on their device by just having the jar (or whatever object it is). If this is done by making a jar, how does one install the app once they have the jar?

Comment: you want specifically jar to install app or generating apk will also serve the purpose

Comment: Is there a specific method I need to go through to generate this jar/apk?

Comment: no apk is easiliy generated there is option in android studio

Comment: Okay, and then how do I install the app on my device if I have the apk on my machine and the device connected via usb?

Comment: Check my answer it might solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate apk

Go Build option in Tool bar of Android Studio

click Generate Apk

Locate the Generated apk on disk and transfer or copy that apk file to mobile device

open apk file from mobile and it is got installed

Answer (score 1):

Connect mobile to pc through usb, Run command **adb install yourapp.apk**.

P.S: enable usb debugging in developer option.

Comment: I get the error: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: uninstall the old application, 
clean the project, 
run and reinstall it again